# Acess the table data <td> row by row <tr> individually

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, dynamic

I need to make changes to the DOM.
I need to present the table content using paragaraphs or something like that. For that I need to get the data per each row of table. How can I do this?

HTML example:

```
<table style="width:300px">
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td> 
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td> 
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Output should be something like this - `Jill Smith 50` and `Eve Jackson 94`

I have written something like this, but it goes through all the `<td>` tags in the web page. Not row wise.

```
 $("table").each(function() {
    $("tr").each(function(){
        $("td").each(function(){                
            label = $('td').text(); 
        });         
    alert(label);
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate through rows and then cells

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AK33G/)**

```
$("table tr").each(function(){
  text = "";
  $(this).find('td').each(function(){
     text += $(this).text() + " ";      
  });
    alert(text);
});
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can add the headings contating inside <th> as well like this. because inside the first <tr> tag , <th> tag is there. Need to access both <th> and <td>. <th> only once as it is only inside the first <tr> tag.

Comment: You probably need to change something like,   $(this).find('td, th').each(function () {... See this in demo, http://jsfiddle.net/AK33G/2/

Comment: Thank you very much. So nice of you Mr.

Comment: Hey You have any idea how to add the table headings <th> to variables or something and use it in every <td> tag. For example In the last demo u send me, I want to get the output like - column1 Jill , Column2 Smith , Column3 50. And the other row also same way column1 Eve , Column2 Jackson , Column3 94 http://jsfiddle.net/AK33G/2/

Comment: Like after going through each <tr> tag needs to check wether <th> or <td> if it's <th> then save those colum names (headings) into an array or something as we don't know the exact number of columns. and then when going through each <td> tag can add that column name infont. Thank you. Hope you will help me sir

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
var groupedVales = [];

$('table tr').each(function(){
  groupedVales[groupedVales.length] = 
          $(this).find('td').map(function(){ $(this).text(); }).get().join(' ');
});
```

Now the `groupedvales` contains elements which will be grouped as per your expectations

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AK33G/1/)

Answer (score 1):

try,

```
   FLAG = true;
    text2 = "";
    $("table tr").each(function(){  
       text1="";       
       $(this).find('td').each(function(){
         text1 += $(this).text() + " ";      
         });
        if(FLAG)
        {
           text2=text1+" "+"and"+"  "
           FLAG=false;
        }
        else
        {
            text2+=text1
        }  
    });
    alert(text2);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("table tr").each(function (i, val) {
   var t=$(this).map(function (i, val) {
    return $(this).text();
   }).get();
   alert(t);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uVrML/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>***[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bEYQ6/1/)***</kbd>

```
$('table tr').each(function () {
    $('body').append($(this).text() + "<br/>");
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Iterate through each `<tr>` `.text()` property...

Answer (score 0):

Give an ID to the table (for instance: mytable) and then do something like this:

```
$("#mytable").find("tr").each(function () {
  var rowtext = "";
  $(this).find("td").each(function () {
    rowtext += $(this).text() + " ";
  });
});
```

Why the ID? ID selectors are faster than element selectors and ensures the code runs only for the table you want, if you want the same code to run on multiple tables a class selector would be ideal.

Why not $("#mytable tr")? jquery reads the selectors right to left, this means that jquery would first find every "tr" element in the document and then filter by wether they have a parent with the id "mytable". Separating the selectors like this: $("#mytable").find("tr") ensures jquery only selects "tr" elements inside the element with "mytable" id.

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution. You can try!

```
$('table tr').each(function(i,e){
    temp=[];
    $(this).find('td').each(function(){
        temp.push($(this).text());
    });
    resultBlock.append('"' + temp.join(' ') + '"');

    if($(this).index()!=($('table tr').length-1)) resultBlock.append(' and ');
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/u9ZYd/)**